# how to put this.state into a variable that will not change after the state changes?

Tags: reactjs

simple question(i hope)
how can i save this.state into a var, without it will change when the this.state changes?
the question will be more clear with the code

```
this.state={x: "123"}
function change(){
   this.setState({x: "456")}
}
```

so again, i wanna put the first state into a var, that will NEVER change, even after we use change()
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the value in an instance level variable in the class [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor).

```js
constructor(props) {
  this.myPermanentState = {x: "123"};
  this.state = {x: "123"};
}

// now calling change will not affect the value of `myPermanentState`
function change(){
   this.setState({x: "456"});
   console.log(this.myPermanentState);
}
```

If you are using React 16 with hooks, you might be able to use the `useRef` hook for similar results.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable that contains the initial state and assign its value to `this.state`.

```
const initialState = {x: "123"};
...
this.state = initialState;
```